# Use of diff command from tcl script captures error 'child process exited abnormally'

Tags: diff, try-catch, tcl

In tcl script I am using diff command to compare the files line by line

```
if {[catch {eval exec "diff /tmp/tECSv2_P_HTTP_XHDR_URL_FUNC_12.itcl /tmp/tempReformat"} results]} {

    puts "$results"
}
```

Output of diff command is obtained properly but it catches error 'child process exited abnormally'

Output:

```
==>tclsh diffUsingScript

992c992
<             fail "Redirection is not reflected in css messages"
---
>         fail "Redirection is not reflected in css messages"
child process exited abnormally
```

So whats going wrong due to which this error is obtained. I want diff operation to be error free in my tcl script

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my `diff(1)`: "Exit status is 0 if inputs are the same, 1 if different, 2 if trouble."

Since non-zero returns are the usual way to report errors in shell scripts, tcl and diff disagree on the meaning of the return result. It's probably really convenient for writing shell scripts to know whether or not two files are different from the return value, but I don't see any mechanism to disable that from the manpage. (I'd rather use `cmp -q` for just getting whether or not two files are different, not sure why the diff people made the decision they did.)

But you can bludgeon this into working by appending `; true` to your command.

A more artful way to make it work would be to error only on an exit code of `2`: `diff foo bar ; if [ $? -ne 2 ]; then true ; else false; fi;`

Check the results with different filenames and `echo $?` after each test to see which ones are returning `0` (from `true`) and which ones are returning `1` (from `false`).

Comment: Anyone know why I couldn't get `if [ $? -neq 2 ] ; then true ; else false ; fi;` to function? Bash returns: `bash: [: -neq: binary operator expected`

Comment: Shouldn't it be -ne rather than -neq?

Comment: Thanks @Jackson ! Fix incorporated, because it is much nicer this way. :)

Comment: Yaah, now i am checking the exit code of 2 for reporting error. But the question of getting message 'child process exited abnormally' when exit code is 1 is still unanswered.

Comment: So, `catch {exec sh -c {diff foo bar; [ $? -lt 2 ] && true || false}} output`

Comment: @vaichidrewar: an exit code that is non-zero is considered "abnormal" by Tcl. That's why you're getting the "child process exited abnormally" message. Tcl has no way of knowing that for this specific program an exit status of 1 is "normal" so it reports an abnormal termination.

Answer (score 0):

The way to handle this in Tcl is:

```
set rc [catch {exec diff f1 f2} output]
if {$rc == 0} {
    puts "no difference"
} else {
    if {[lindex $::errorCode 0] eq "CHILDSTATUS"} {
        if {[lindex $::errorCode 2] == 1} {
            puts "difference"
            # show output without "child process exited abnormally" message
            puts [string replace $output end-31 end ""]
        } else {
            puts "diff error: $output"
        }
    } else {
        puts "error calling diff: $output"
    }
}
```

See the discussion on the Tcl Wiki [exec page](http://wiki.tcl.tk/exec).

Comment: When the above code was executed got the following error: syntax error in expression "[lindex $::errorCode 0] eq CHILDSTATUS": variable references require preceding $
    ("if" test expression)
    while compiling
"if {[lindex $::errorCode 0] eq CHILDSTATUS} {

Comment: ah right, I should have a "bareword" in an expression.  I'll fix it.